# Coordinator Behavior ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm having some trouble with my CoordinatorLayout. When I scroll up I want the imageview to disappear completely.

This is an example of view and after i scroll up
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewV5f.jpg

**planet_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/ctlLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userAvatar"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_large"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_large"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/pl_alderaan"
                android:padding="2dp"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userLogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:text="Header"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Subheader"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/card"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/lorum"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I've also attempted to implement a custom behavior after finding a few examples on, especially this GitHub app example by[Gitskarios](https://github.com/gitskarios/Gitskarios/blob/4600b892542067ccc4dc4969952c01fb56a2184a/app/src/main/java/com/alorma/github/ui/utils/AvatarImageBehavior.java) since our layouts are similar but it does not fix my issue. I also read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735603/coordinator-layout-custom-layout-behavior-never-getting-called) that it may not be getting called due to it not being a direct child. How do I keep my layout and fade/hide the imageview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy method is to use `app:contentScrim="@color/your_toolbar_color"` on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Technically this won't get rid of the image, it will just cover it with your toolbar's color again, but it will appear to fade out and in.

Comment: That fixed my issue! Thank you very much that was embarrassingly simple.